# PHPDoc Comment, Class vs File

Tags: php, documentation

I am trying to standardise my code as much as possible, including DocComments, using [PHPCS](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.php).

It seems that the PEAR standards contain two sniffs that require almost exactly the same tags appear in the Class and File DocBlocks:

```
PEAR.Commenting.ClassComment
PEAR.Commenting.FileComment
```

Both of these want to see these tags: `@category`, `@package`, `@author`, `@license`, `@link`.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 10 ERRORS AFFECTING 2 LINES
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  6 | ERROR | Missing @category tag in file comment
  6 | ERROR | Missing @package tag in file comment
  6 | ERROR | Missing @author tag in file comment
  6 | ERROR | Missing @license tag in file comment
  6 | ERROR | Missing @link tag in file comment
 13 | ERROR | Missing @category tag in class comment
 13 | ERROR | Missing @package tag in class comment
 13 | ERROR | Missing @author tag in class comment
 13 | ERROR | Missing @license tag in class comment
 13 | ERROR | Missing @link tag in class comment
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It would be silly to repeat these because all my source files contain just a single class (or interface or trait).

My question is, which tags should go where. Should they all go in the file comment, all in the class comment, or should they be split between the two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on what I can find, this is my own opinion which I pose as an answer. I would really like feedback on this. *This answer is based on a proposed (not-accepted) standard.*

### Breakdown:

Looking through the [proposed PSR-5 standard](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md), particularly the description of each tag helped a bit.

**[@category](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#83-category-deprecated)**

Deprecated in favour of @package which does essentially the same thing, so can be removed from the sniff.

**[@package](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#812-package)**

Can be used in either, however in the file block it applies to: global functions, global constants, global variables, requires and includes. In the class it applies to the class and all containing elements. Assuming that your file only contains a class, the @package tag would be meaningless in the file block.

**[@author](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#82-author)**

This can apply to any structural element. The documentation doesn't specifically help answer the question of which, however since the file contains the class, I would say this should appear in the most encompassing element (the file comment), with other authors adding an @author tag to any sub elements they write.

**[@license](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#89-license)**

Again, this can be applied to any structural element, but is applied to all sub elements, therefore the file seems most appropriate.

**[@link](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#810-link-deprecated)**

Link is also deprecated in favour of @see

So:

**[@see](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#816-see)**

@see is looser than @link, and could happily be applied to both the file and the class. For example the file could reference the project website, the file could reference the documentation for the class.

### Summary:

So this is what I think the file should roughly look like

```
<?php
/**
 * FileName.php
 * @author    My Name <email@example.com>
 * @copyright 2015 My Company
 * @license   Licence Name
 * @see       Link to project website
 */

namespace My/Namespace;

use Another/Namespace/Class;

/**
 * Class summary
 * A longer class description
 * @package Vendor/Project
 * @see     Link to class documentation
 */
class MyClass {
    ...
}
```